# Layer-2-Accessible DMZ: ebtables?

Tags: networking, router, iptables, dmz

I'd like to make a network topology where all the IoT devices (printer, DVR, thermostat, BluRay player, etc) are all in a DMZ and the rest of my devices are all on the LAN. Note that the usage of *DMZ* here is different from the *DMZ* settings on routers and refers to a "zone of the network I put devices I don't trust to not try to hack my network".

Normally, this is done by making tiered gateways (i.e. have a gateway within the DMZ to protect the LAN) or having a custom 3-way gateway with special iptables rules. I've done both before, but both suffer from the problem that they are a layer-3 solution and I'm looking for a layer-2 solution, primarily to preserve mDNS and Service Discovery working.

What I think I want is to allow:

LAN --[anything]--> DMZ

DMZ --[established+broadcasts+DHCP]--> LAN

However, looking at the `ebtables` documentation, it doesn't look like I can differentiate between *established* ip connections and *new* ip connections, which is a required feature of my plan.

So, there are two possibilities that come from this:

1) Determining how to use `ebtables` to do what I want; or

2) Using the double-NAT approach and having a device (RasPi or something) listen for Service Discovery broadcasts on the DMZ and relay them on the LAN.

The final question: **Which approach is possible and/or easiest-to-manage from the perspective of how long I'm going to be fiddling with things to make it work?**

Note: tagging under `iptables` instead of `ebtables` because I apparently cannot create that tag...

Comment: How are you defining an "established" IP connection?  Do you mean TCP given that IP is stateless?

Comment: Layer-2 is problematic for what you want since it is a totally peer-to-peer network. There are switches which can do Private VLANs (devices in the same VLAN cannot talk to each other) or layer-2, MAC-based ACLs (which are ugly, being based on MAC addresses of each device).

Comment: Yes, I mean TCP (or emulated/assumed in UDP). I'm using that term because that's how `iptables` refers to it.

Answer (score 0):

First, `ebtables` is a Link-Layer protocol, and, as such, it cannot possibly know anything about `ESTABLISHED, RELATED` connections. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_layer),

> The link layer is the group of methods and communications protocols that only operate on the link that a host is physically connected to.

So, how can it know that this packet from some remote URL is the next packet in a series that was initiated locally?

As for your second solution, it is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Generally, DMZs are used to limit the amount of traffic exchanged between it and the non-DMZ LAN, exactly to prevent network discovery and/or probing, and so on. You instead are trying to increase the protocols and communications between the two.

If you want to do that, why not just make a single LAN encompassing both DMZ and non-DMZ, and then screen traffic thru `iptables`? This way, you will allow non-IP traffic between the two, but may block IP traffic, like dropping all ssh/telnet connections from one zone to the other.

Alternatively, you may use a kind of Man in the Middle, *i.e.* a pc with an interface on the non-DMZ and one on the DMZ, with IPv4-forwarding enabled but controlled by `iptables`, and `dhcp-relay` to allow the passing of DHCP requests (the version provided by `dnsmaq` is especially easy to setup). Also, you could enable [Proxy-ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP) on this MIM pc, so that it will reply to ARP queries on behalf of the quarantined machines.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Firstly, I know ebtables is layer-2; however, it HAS ability to snoop packets and filter based on source IP, dest IP, port, etc. that's how it knows: it snoops. Also, public web servers and the IoT require a different kind of DMZ: one you insulate and one you want to use, but don't trust with free reign. I also specifically mentioned that I do not want to use iptables or have a custom gateway.

Comment: @iAdjunct I think you are mistaken: you should read what Bart de Schuymer, the author of ebtables, has to say about its capabilities, especially in connection with ESTABLISHED., https://sourceforge.net/p/ebtables/mailman/message/2821657/

Comment: All that tells me is that ebtables doesn't snoop for those. However, it does not give confidence that iptables will apply to bridged connections when the traffic is across the bridge and not destined for the local computer.

Comment: @iAdjunct Precisely, `ebtables` knows nothing about ESTABLISHED,CONNECTED. So your question n. 1 is answered. As for not wanting to use iptables or a custom gateway, that's like kicking and cussing: they make your mood transparent, but they do not make a solution any nearer.

Comment: I can't tell what your last paragraph in your answer is going towards (does it act like a bridge or a gateway? It is unclear). Would you please elaborate on it in an edit?